# Get different part of a selected value

Tags: jquery

I have three different parts in the value, when i choose a country, who are seperated with an Pipe "|".
How can i take the values between the seperator in my thre input fields.

Here a demo [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achillix/hkKbb/5/)

The first value is the City, the second the street of the city and the third is the code postal. How can i get the three values seperated in the inputfields

```
---------------------------------------
Country Germany
City: Berlin
Street: Musterstrasse 16
Code Postal: 16500
---------------------------------------
```

THX in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#country").change(
   function () {
       var pieces = $(this).val().split('|');
       if(pieces.length === 3) {         
           $("#capital").val(pieces[0]);
           $("#street").val(pieces[1]);
           $("#cp").val(pieces[2]);
       }                          
   }
).trigger('change');
```

make a trigger to initialize!

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
   $("#country").change(
       function () {
           var value = $(this).val().split("|");
           $("#capital").val((value[0]));
           $("#street").val((value[1]));
           $("#cp").val((value[2]));
       }
   );​
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#country").change(
function() {
    $("#capital").val($(this).val().split('|')[0]);
    $("#street").val($(this).val().split('|')[1]);
    $("#cp").val($(this).val().split('|')[2]);
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hkKbb/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `split("|")` to split the value by `|` character. This assumes that the capital, street and code postal doesn't contain the `|` character.

```
$("#country").change(
    function () {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        var tokens = selected.split("|");
        $("#capital").val(tokens[0]);
        $("#street").val(tokens[1]);
        $("#cp").val(tokens[2]);
    }
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hkKbb/6/

Comment: @achillix: You should have a look at silly's answer. It is way better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Get the index with

```
$(this).prop("selectedIndex");
```

and split the values with

```
$(this).val().split('|')[index];
```

Sample

```
   $("#country").change(
       function () {
           $("#capital").val($(this).val());
           $("#street").val($(this).val());
           $("#cp").val($(this).val());
       }
   );
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3PxG/)